# Angular - Dynamic Access Control Manager, Role / Permissions based on function in class service

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I need every user have a permissions / role to access every menu, tabs even action in angular and show hide the menu by the permissions.

My concept, 
1. Mapping / Scan function in every class service.
2. The result of scanned function, saved in database and create the CRUD UI, so we can choose what the role / permissions to give the user.

The question, can this concept be made?

Any one, any idea?
Please advise

Answer (score 1):

The mapping for such case is always on your database, so you can fetch all permissions while user login to your system, and to show hide components, you can make only one function that returns boolean if the user has required permission; then simply use **ngIf** to check the permission.

Comment: Yes, for now. I mapping the service manually, one by one. And it's so tired. I want to scan all file service and get the function in each class, can it?

Comment: Of course you can, if you made your function in a global service class, then injecting this service anywhere in you system and call the method directly.

Comment: So, when I click button Scan, the script will inject every service class and find a function and then save it to database. Can you tell me what the technical to make it?

Comment: I didn’t get the point, save what? and what that button is actually doing?

Comment: I have scheme like this: the first, we generate all method in class service by  click button Scan. And the results will save into DB.  The button is a trigger to scan entire method in class service, so we can assign permission to user by the result of generator method in class service

Comment: Maybe you can see extension of PHP Yii2 Mimin, RBAC manager. I want to make similar of that extension for Angular

Comment: Then this is custom implementation , and for sure this is applicable in angular, by the way you're doing javascript at the end, check this may helps https://medium.com/@eliasmsedano/angular-4-how-to-check-authorization-based-on-role-and-entity-states-cf0282280961

Comment: Ok, I will check it, and tell you the result what I found.